Anime where the main character is transferred to the bottom of the dungeon or labyrinth because he was seen as being useless
I'm looking for an anime I saw a bit back around the end of 2023 for future 2024 anime.
The start of the anime is where the main character is randomly picked along with a bunch of other people into a labyrinth or dungeon with a god I think it was. Everyone was given powers but his was seen as useless, so he was transferred into the bottom of the dungeon or labyrinth and decides to climb back to the top of the labyrinth or dungeon to get his revenge.
If anyone can find or tell me the name of the anime, I would appreciate it and thank you for taking the time to try to find it for me.

Did you watch this on TV or online?

You're certain this is for a 2024 anime? Any idea which season it would air in? Was it definitely a new thing? This sounds a bit like Arifureta, which apparently does have a third season coming in winter 2024, but the "abandoned in the bottom of the dungeon" bit happens immediately so I doubt it'd be in an advert for the third season.

This may be Failure Frame: I Became the Strongest and Annihilated Everything With Low-Level Spells. The anime is due to come out in Summer 2024. The trailer for the anime is here. I couldn't find an English translation on youtube, so I'll borrow details from a story identification question for the source manga:
The manga starts out with a goddess addressing the class she just summoned and informs them that the main character is to be disposed of because he has the lowest aptitude and will bring down all the others. A single student tries to stand up for him, but the goddess then knocks her out claiming his mere presences is already leading one of the highest aptitude members astray. The rest of the class then insults and isolates him. He is then teleported into a dungeon where he finds out his skills are poison, paralysis, and sleep. He manages to paralyze the monster that initially attacks him, and then uses it to determine the limits of his abilities until it dies.

That sounds like Arifureta: From Commonplace to World's Strongest, there are 3 seasons. The main character, Nagamo, a synergist (seen as a worthless skill in combat), falls to a lower level when the bridge he's standing on get destroyed in the first episode and decides to go to the lowest level to see if there's another way out of the dungeon. There's no god in the party though.
This story is much older than 2023, it aired in 2019, season 2 however aired in 2022, with season 3 yet to be released.
Here's a teaser to see if you recognise the characters (I don't know how to embed a video).
That is the only recent anime I've seen that involves a character, part of a group of isekaied students, being abandoned in a dungeon.

He wasn’t transferred to the bottom but was attacked by a single classmate and fell close to the bottom. Later he goes deeper in order to get out.
